# Find 2 Strings in sentence within certain distance

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to presence of 2 strings in any order within certain distance between them

for example I have 2 sentences below

```
sentence = "Tiger is eating meat"
sentence = "Meat is eaten by Tiger"
```

I want to search for Tiger and Meat

My regex currently does this but there is no limit on how far apart Tiger and mean can be. It will always return search result when Tiger and meat are next to each other or 100's of strings apart. I want to limit number of words between Tiger and meat to say 5

```
re.search(r"(?=.*Tiger)(?=.*Meat)", sentence, re.IGNORECASE)
```

or

```
re.search(r"(?=.*Meat)(?=.*Tiger)", sentence, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Ideally I would like to have one regex to search for tiger and meat in any order , but can live with 2 regex. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using the following regex pattern:

```
tiger (\S+ ){0,5}meat|meat (\S+ ){0,5}tiger
```

The term `(\S+ ){0,5}` matches between zero and five words in between `tiger` and `meat`.  We use an alternation to allow for `tiger` and `meat` to occur in either order.

Sample script:

```
sentence = "Tiger aaa bbb ccc ddd eee meat"
if re.match(r'tiger (\S+ ){0,5}meat|meat (\S+ ){0,5}tiger', sentence, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("MATCH")
```

This prints `MATCH`, but the following input sentence would fail and not print anything:

```
sentence = "Tiger aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff meat"
```

Comment: you can replace spaces by `\s` in your regex too

Comment: Yes, and I sometimes do that, but I was thinking that perhaps the OP really only wants to match space characters (and not other types of whitespace).